# Is this function decreasing at its points of discontinuity?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have a real valued function $V (t)$. It is continuous at all points except a countable of number of points $t_k $ at which it has jump discontunities. Now this sequence $\{t_k\} $ is strictly increasing. And $V (t) $ is right continuous at all these points such that $V (t_k)\leq V (t_k^-) $ for all $k\in\mathbb {N}.$ Then can i say that $V (t_k)\leq V (t_{k-1}) $ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}?$ The reasons for this intuition are  $V (t) $ is continuous at all points except $t_k,$ the left limit of $V (t)$ at $t_k $ is greater than $V (t_k)$ and $t_{k-1} $ lies to left of $t_k $?

Comment: Choose $V$ to have a massive decline between 2  neighboring discontinuities, and make the discontinuities small.

Comment: @SenZen i don't get. Are you telling me this intuition is not correct in general?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4rgtxirlyt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition fails. A simple counter-example is $V(x)=x^{2}-[x]$ with $t_k=k$ for all $k$. In this case $V(t_2) >V(t_1)$.

Comment: Is the defined V right continous such that $V (t_k)\leq V (t_k^-)?$

Comment: Yes, it satisfies those conditions.  [ $k^{2}-k \leq k^{2}-(k-1)]$@shwetha

Comment: Thank you so much.